# HLS. Decrypt segments with EXT-X-BYTERANGE

Tags: encryption, aes, http-live-streaming, http-range

Let's say we have HLS segments encrypted with AES-128 method. But segments data restricted with EXT-X-BYTERANGE. Could you please advice me how I can decrypt this?
Can I download this part of data with HTTP range request, and then decrypt this data with key and IV, or decryptor must be initialize from begin of the segment?

```
…
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://server/file.key",IV=0x1d48fc5dee84b5a3e9a428f055e03c2e
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:92580@822
//vidione.loc/storage/AEFIXUum/res-0/segment.m4s
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:124656@93402
//vidione.loc/storage/AEFIXUum/res-0/segment.m4s
…
```